# Disk Utility reading disk incorrectly; viewing ext4 as JHFS+ and seeing Recovery HD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, osx-yosemite, macbook-pro-retina

So, I have some strange issues in Disk Utility and diskutil. It's not a problem (hopefully), but I just want to make sure that I'm not on the path to disk corruption or failure. This is how my disk utility reads my hard disk:

(as they are listed)

- Disk Description  : APPLE SSD SD0256F Media
- Total Capacity    : 251 GB (251,000,193,024 Bytes)
- Connection Bus    : PCI
- Write Status :  Read/Write
- Type and Location : Solid State Disk, Internal
- S.M.A.R.T. Status : Verified
- Partition Map Scheme :  GUID Partition Table

And here are the partitions:

- Macintosh HD

  - Format : Mac OS Extended (journaled)
  - Size : 202.66 GB
- Recovery HD

  - Format : Mac OS Extended (journaled)
  - Size : 650 MB
- disk0s4

  - Format : Mac OS Extended (journaled)
  - Size : 46.8 GB
- disk0s6

  - Format : Linux Swap
  - Size : 681.6 MB

The reason for my worry is two things: 1) Recovery HD is visible, which, I could be mistaken, but this shouldn't be visible OR mounted in Disk Utility, and 2) disk0s4 is actually ext4, NOT JHFS+.

Output from diskutil list:

```
    /dev/disk0
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
       2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            202.7 GB   disk0s2
       3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
       4: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               46.8 GB    disk0s4
       5:                 Linux Swap                         681.6 MB   disk0s6
```

And from gdisk...

```
    >sudo gdisk /dev/disk0
    Password:
    GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

    Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
    partition table automatically reloaded!
    Partition table scan:
      MBR: hybrid
      BSD: not present
      APM: not present
      GPT: present

    Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.

    Command (? for help): p
    Disk /dev/disk0: 490234752 sectors, 233.8 GiB
    Logical sector size: 512 bytes
    Disk identifier (GUID): B01E51EA-D531-4CA4-ADA4-A936F8C27DCD
    Partition table holds up to 128 entries
    First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 490234718
    Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
    Total free space is 949 sectors (474.5 KiB)

    Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
       1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
       2          409640       396222607   188.7 GiB   AF00  Macintosh HD
       3       396222608       397492143   619.9 MiB   AF00  Recovery HD
       4       397492224       488902655   43.6 GiB    8300  
       6       488902656       490233855   650.0 MiB   8200  Apple_HFS_Untitled_2

    Command (? for help): ^C>
```

I have used gdisk before to make my hard drive hybridized MBR/GPT and have installed Ubuntu 14.04.

Anyone have an inkling to why this is, where is disk0s5, and will this be a problem?

EDIT:

gpt has this output -

```
    >sudo gpt -vvv show /dev/disk0
    Password:
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=251000193024; sectorsize=512; blocks=490234752
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: MBR part: type=175, start=409640, size=395812968
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: MBR part: type=175, start=396222608, size=1269536
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: MBR part: type=131, start=397492224, size=91410432
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, start=40, size=409600
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=409640, size=395812968
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=396222608, size=1269536
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, start=397492224, size=91410432
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F, start=488902656, size=1331200
    gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 490234751
          start       size  index  contents
              0          1         MBR
              1          1         Pri GPT header
              2         32         Pri GPT table
             34          6         
             40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
         409640  395812968      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
      396222608    1269536      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
      397492144         80         
      397492224   91410432      4  GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
      488902656    1331200      6  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
      490233856        863         
      490234719         32         Sec GPT table
      490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

and fdisk...:

```
    >sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
    Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30515/255/63 [490234752 sectors]
    Signature: 0xAA55
             Starting       Ending
     #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1: EE    0   0   1 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
    *2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  395812968] HFS+        
     3: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 396222608 -    1269536] HFS+        
     4: 83 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 397492224 -   91410432] Linux files*
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see what OS X's `gpt` and `fdisk` commands say about it. Both `sudo gpt -vvv show /dev/disk0` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`.

Comment: If it helps, GParted has _no_ difficulty whatsoever identifying the disks for what they are. Looking at this again, what is that one byte-sized MBR at the top of my disk?

Comment: Well, your recovery partition shows up because something (probably gdisk, when making the hybrid partition table) changed the GPT partition type GUID from 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (Apple Boot/Recovery partition) to 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (Apple HFS+). The MBR at the top of your disk is your MBR. It's one *block* (512 bytes), not one byte. I can't explain why Disk Utility is reporting an ext4 partition as JHFS+.

Comment: Huh. I've never seen anything like this before (given my question) and have found no reference to it online, so I'd like to figure out what I did. Also, slightly related, my Ubuntu and linux-swap partitions are impervious to disk utility (undeletable). I know this happens with linux-swap (not my first time doing this). The Ubuntu partition causes the error "Unidentified Filesystem", which I assume means that it knows it's not JHFS+, yet refuses to accept that whenever it is displayed normally in Disk Utility.